# Error construyendo un JSON en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy tratando de construir un JSOn desde PHP, pero cuando pongo dos condiciones no me genera los datos.

Es decir necesito solamente traer los datos de **SARA**, pero cuando pongo traerlos por **id_ppl** y por **nivel** al mismo tiempo no consigo nada. no se realmente que estoy haciendo mal.

lo probe por postman cambiando las variables, traerlo solo por id, o por usuario y funciona, pero cuando pongo las dos anteriores no consigo nada.

Tabla

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | id_ppl | nivel | multi  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Juana     | *****    |       | 1      | 1     | on     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Sara      | *****    |       | 1      | 2     | on     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

PHP Script

```
require 'conn.php';

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Gagal terhubung MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"]; 
    $nivel = $_GET["nivel"]; 
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, nivel, multi FROM escolar_users WHERE id_ppl = '$id' AND nivel='$nivel'");

    $json = '{"loadUser": [';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


        $char ='"';

        $json .= 
        '{
            "id":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row['id'])).'",
            "nivel":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row['nivel'])).'", 
            "multi":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row['multi'])).'"
        },';
    }

    // buat menghilangkan koma diakhir array
    $json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

    $json .= ']}';

    // print json
    echo $json;

    mysqli_close($connect);
```

URL método GET

```
load.php?id_ppl=1&nivel=2
```

Comment: En tu tabla no hay ningun registro que tenga id=1 y nivel=2

Comment: Pero en el query select, espcifico que debe elegir id_ppl y nivel el $id q trae es solo un numero de referencia

Answer (score 4):

Estas haciendo el json a la manera dificil ,hay una funcion ya pre-establecida de php que se llama [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php).

La query intenta hacerla a si, sin las comillas simple:

```
$query = "SELECT id, nivel, multi FROM escolar_users WHERE id_ppl = $id AND nivel = $nivel";
```

**Ejemplos de json_encode:**

```
$test = array(
    "success" => true,
    "msg" => $message,
    "id" => $value
)

echo json_encode($test);

#output
{"success":true,"msg":"","id":100}
```

**Plus:**

- Que no se te olvide usar `header('Content-Type: application/json');` en la parte arriba de tu funcion para que se muestre como json el sitio web/pagina.
- hay extensiones en google chrome para mostrar bonito el json, solo buscalas